# Snowflake merge command is returning invalid identifier at the ON clause

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to merge data from a stage into an existing table using a procedure. Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_OBSERVATION_VALUES(FILE_FULL_PATH STRING, FILE_FORMAT_NAME STRING, 
                                                   OBSERVATION_DATE_POSITION FLOAT, LOCATION_POSITION FLOAT)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
try{
var observarion_query = "MERGE INTO HUB_OBSERVATION AS OBS "+
"USING (SELECT DATE(T.$"+OBSERVATION_DATE_POSITION+", 'DD/MM/YYYY'), T.$"+LOCATION_POSITION+" FROM "+FILE_FULL_PATH+"(FILE_FORMAT=>"+FILE_FORMAT_NAME+") T) ST "+
"ON md5(CONCAT(DATE(ST.$"+OBSERVATION_DATE_POSITION+", 'DD/MM/YYYY'), CONCAT('CAMP', ST.$"+LOCATION_POSITION+"))) = OBS.OBSERVATION_DATE_LOCATION_HASH_KEY "+
"WHEN MATCHED AND OBS.LOAD_END_DT=NULL THEN UPDATE SET OBS.LOAD_END_DT = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() "+
"WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN "+
"INSERT (OBSERVATION_DATE_LOCATION_HASH_KEY, LOAD_DT, LOAD_END_DT, RECORD_SRC, OBSERVATION_DATE, LOCATION_NAME) "+
"VALUES (md5(CONCAT(ST.$"+OBSERVATION_DATE_POSITION+", CONCAT('CAMP', ST.$"+LOCATION_POSITION+"))), current_timestamp(), NULL, 'ONA', ST.$"+OBSERVATION_DATE_POSITION+", CONCAT('CAMP', ST.$"+LOCATION_POSITION+")) "

}
catch(error){
    return error;
}
```

When calling the procedure:

I am getting the following error:

> SQL compilation error: error line 3 at position 14 invalid identifier
> 'ST.$7'

when I tried to run the merge outside of the procedure:

```
MERGE INTO HUB_OBSERVATION AS OBS
USING (SELECT DATE(T.$7, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), T.$6 FROM @ingest_stage_temp/data.csv.gz (FILE_FORMAT=>"GENERIC_CSV_FORMAT") T) ST 
ON md5(CONCAT(ST.$7, CONCAT('CAMP', ST.$6))) = OBS.OBSERVATION_DATE_LOCATION_HASH_KEY 
WHEN MATCHED AND OBS.LOAD_END_DT=NULL THEN UPDATE SET OBS.LOAD_END_DT = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (OBSERVATION_DATE_LOCATION_HASH_KEY, LOAD_DT, LOAD_END_DT, RECORD_SRC, OBSERVATION_DATE, LOCATION_NAME) 
VALUES (md5(CONCAT(ST.$7, CONCAT('CAMP', ST.$6))), current_timestamp(), NULL, 'ONA', ST.$7, CONCAT('CAMP', ST.$6));
```

I've got the same error.

Comment: Do you have 7 columns or less?

Comment: I have 33 columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give the alias to `TO_DATE` expression in `USING` clause and then you can use it outside `USING` clause with the given alias name as follows:

```
....
....
USING (SELECT DATE(T.$7, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as $7 ... -- this
....
....
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked with an extra edit to the script. I am re-converting it again into DATE but there is no need as it is converted inside `USING`.